# How to figure out why deployment failed in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I was trying to pack up the Angular project I input the directive to cmd: `ng build --prod`, after few minutes, I deployed the project by IIS. But I can't visit the project in brower. There is something wrong in console.

[image]

What are `r` and `n`? I really don't know. I pack up again, but use the directive: `ng build`. And everything successful. But the size of the project is bigger than `ng build --prod`.
What should I do to figure out the error?

Comment: With the `--prod` flag various things are changed (see [the `ng build` docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)). The single letter variables are the result of *minification*, one of the ways the bundle sizes are reduced. Set the various build flags one at a time to see which is causing your issue; I'd guess AOT.

Comment: have you followed angulars AoT Guide? (https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)
Your code has to be statically analyzable (for example, dont use arrow functions as factory methods in your modules providers array)

Comment: @Arikael The compiler never hesitates to throw errors about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the source map along with the bundles and then figure out where exactly the error is. You can do this on your local to run with `AOT` along with `sourcemaps`

```
ng serve --aot -sourcemaps
```

If your source maps are not getting generated, you can follow the link [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles) to get them.