# Angular 5.2.9 production build issues

Tags: angular

Running fine on `ng build` but after creating production build on Angular 5.2.9, the production build throws this error:

```
main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(r)[n -> n]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
    at n.get (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1
    at n (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at n.get (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1
    at n (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at n.get (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at Mr (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
    at main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1
    at Dr (main.3dc2d6370c3c3aa5fa33.bundle.js:1)
```

Comment: I have answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334802/how-to-figure-out-why-deployment-failed-in-angular/49336133#49336133

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use CookieService you make to sure these steps

## **app.module.ts**

```
import { CookieService ,CookieOptions} from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import ....

export function cookieServiceFactory() {
  return new CookieService();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
     ...
               ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ],
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    { provide: CookieOptions, useValue: {} },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Solved my problem with an Angular 6 app: I had `CookieService` listed in providers, but not `CookieOptions`. Production build was broken because of this (`StaticInjectorError`).